# Jquery mobile: how to execute custom jquery code in page

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am currently developing a mobile site using jQuery mobile.

I have one simple piece of jQuery that i would like to execute on a button click

eg: Click button, show div. This works fine on the first page, or any page which is directly accessed by url. However, wherever there is page history (ie url contains the a #) the custom snippet of jQuery simply doesn't execute. I'm assuming it's something to do with the location.hash

I've had a good trawl through the jQuery mobile docs and google but can't find any reference to this issue.

Any ideas how i can get this piece of jQuery to execute at all times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create in your JS code a function that you want to execute(let's call it function savePerson()). Create the button with:

```
<button onclick="savePerson()">Save</button>
```

Comment: thanks, still have the same issue, appears to be related to the ajax loading of links. As soon as i turn that off, jquery works on all pages... odd.

Comment: do mark your selected answer as valid to help other with the same doubts. It's the highlight green check image that appears on each answer, click in one. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For run the custom scripts on jquery mobile page you can follow this link:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/api/globalconfig.html

I recommend wich you run your code inside a "delegate" event, how[1]:

```
$(“body”).delegate(“div[data-role*='page']“, “pageshow”, function(){

    // Your code here. It is good to check to not run unnecessary code

});
```

[1]http://www.raelmax.com/2011/03/06/minha-experiencia-com-jquery-mobile/

Comment: Thanks rael, it seemed that my issue was due to using id's, your article helped greatly :) I changed my trigger ids to classes and the div id to a class and it started to work great :)